# Pusher Undefined property: stdClass::$channels in Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, pusher

I'm making a POC with Lumen and Vue.JS. For now it just has to send a "hello world" message from the Lumen back-end to the Vue.JS front-end (which works). I have made an event which is triggered upon loading the page like this:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    event(new MessageEvent('hello world'));
}
```

The MessageEvent looks like this (got this from the Pusher getting started help):

```
class MessageEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
  
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['my-channel'];
    }
  
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }
}
```

This part is working, since I'm receiving this in the Vue.JS application:

```
Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"my-event","channel":"my-channel","data":{"message":"hello world"}}]
```

Now comes the problem when i check the queue log. triggered with `php artisan queue:listen`, I see the following:

```
[2021-03-14 11:57:03][Bh7373O9EETAZc39M2RCSPmUTjwSbSmL] Processing: App\Events\MessageEvent
[2021-03-14 11:57:04][Bh7373O9EETAZc39M2RCSPmUTjwSbSmL] Failed:     App\Events\MessageEvent
```

When I check the Lumen log files it says the following:

```
[2021-03-14 11:43:12] local.ERROR: Undefined property: stdClass::$channels {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: stdClass::$channels at /var/www/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php:538)
```

So I went ahead and checkt the Pusher.php file:

```
536:         $result = json_decode($response['body']);
537:         
538:         if ($result->channels) {
539:             $result->channels = get_object_vars($result->channels);
540:         }
```

I decided to check what `$response` was, it gives the following:

```
[2021-03-14 11:57:04] local.INFO: array (
  'body' => '{}',
  'status' => 200,
)
```

Of course it can't get to `$result->channels` if `response["body"]["channels"]` doesn't exist.

When I go and check the Pusher API reference it says the following:
[image: Response codes and descriptions according to Pusher API reference]

Which would mean that the body should indeed contain a JSON response. But when I scroll a bit further I see this:
[image: Parameters and description according to Pusher API reference]

Which should mean you don't have to set the info parameter, since it's optional and experimental.

```
[EXPERIMENTAL] If the info parameter is sent, then it returns a hash of unique channels that were triggered to. The hash maps from channel name to a hash of attributes for that channel (may be empty).
```

The response it expects with the info parameter set is this:

```
{
  "channels": {
    "presence-foobar": {
      "user_count": 42,
      "subscription_count": 51
    },
    "presence-another": {
      "user_count": 123,
      "subscription_count": 140
    },
    "another": {
      "subscription_count": 13
    }
  }
}
```

Which is the `channels` object asked for.

My question is, did I miss something or is this a bug from Pusher? I'm really breaking a leg on this one so I hope someone can help me out.

Pusher API reference: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/rest-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fix composer.json**

I have created an issue on the PHP package: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/issues/295

It is true this version is broken, but the fix should be in the `composer.json` file. Mine looked like this:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "5.0"
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This means I specifically say that it should use version `5.0`. But now I won't get version `5.2` for example, which means I won't get patches. According to the people who answered my issue on Github, I should change my `composer.json` and add a `^` in front of the version number so it does get the patches for that version. So it should be changed like this:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0"
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to run `composer update` afterwards.

According to Graham Campbell on Github:

> Anyone who puts `5.0` in their `composer.json` file has made an error, since composer resolves this to the version `5.0.0.0` and not the version constraint `^5.0`.

**Fix pusher.php (not recommended)**

Another workaround would be to directly edit `/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php`. Although not recommended, it does work.

```
536:         $result = json_decode($response['body']);
537:         
538:         if ($result->channels) {
539:             $result->channels = get_object_vars($result->channels);
540:         }
```

This doesn't work since `channels` doesnt exist in the `result` object. It should check if the channels object exists first. You can do that by changing the above code to this:

```
536:         $result = json_decode($response['body']);
537:         
538:         if (property_exists($result, 'channels')) {
539:             $result->channels = get_object_vars($result->channels);
540:         }
```